How to avoid defineNuxtConfig is not defined TS error in Nuxt app?
I've created a basic Nuxtapp
My main nuxt.config
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  alias: { '@': '/' },
  modules: [], // Add any Nuxt modules you need here
  hooks: {
    ready: () => {
      console.log('Nuxt is ready!')
    }
  },
  components: true,
  ssr: true,
  css: ['~/assets/css/main.css'],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {}
    }
  }
})

I was getting a TS: defineNuxtConfig is not defined here so I excluded it from my tsconfig.
{
  // https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["nuxt.config.ts"]
}

 ERROR  [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] defineNuxtConfig is not defined

Isn't defineNuxtConfig always suppose to be found in a Nuxt app?
package.json
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.12.4",
    "vue": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "postcss": "^8.4.41",
    "prettier": "3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.10"
  }
}


Try to install the dependencies then restart your IDE
